# app crash when add google login firebaseui

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

When we add  this line `new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()`, the app crashes and shows this error "Check your google-services plugin configuration, the default_web_client_id string wasn't populated"

What to do? I have tried almost all solutions that are suggested in GitHub and StackOverflow but my problem is not solved. My project was working with Google login Firebase UI and I don't know why it is not working now.
If I remove googlebuilder then the app works without any problems.

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.2'



 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files     // in the individual module build.gradle files
       // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
       // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'


    }
```

Comment: for me updating all the libraries to latest version and adding the **key** with string_name `default_web_client_id` solved

Answer (score 0):

I think its an issue in firebase console. I use two different firebase projects to separate dev and prod environments and I started getting this error on production today.

I compared the two generated `google-services.json` files and found out the one that I generated today was missing another object in the `oauth_client` array

This one works - `default_web_client_id` is generated:

```
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "blabalbal-blablabal",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "haha",
        "certificate_hash": "ahaha"
      }
    },
    {
      "client_id": "hahah",
      "client_type": 3
    }
  ],
```

I generated this one today and `default_web_client_id` is not generated from this one

```
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "bababab",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "babab",
        "certificate_hash": "blablbalb"
      }
    }
  ],
```

So the one that works has this extra object:

```
  {
      "client_id": "hahah",
      "client_type": 3
   }
```

where the `client_id` is located in google cloud console -> **APIs & Services** -> **Credentials** -> **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** -> "Web client (auto created by Google Service)"

So I paste that object back in as a temporary solution...

Answer (score -1):

The approach that worked for me was as follows:

1. Login to Google Cloud Console
2. From the menu on the left, select APIs and Services -> Credentials
3. Copy the client ID from the Web Client (auto-created by Google Service) under the "OAuth 2.0 client IDs" section
4. Back in Android Studio, in res -> values -> Strings.xml, create an entry of the form

   ```
   <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">XXXXXXX</string>
   ```

(where XXXXXXX is the client ID you copied from the console in step 3

5. Recompile, the application should work without any problems now.

Comment: you should not add this string yourself, it is supposed to be generated by google services gradle plugin. Technically this will fix it but the root cause is - that gradle plugin didnt generate that string

Answer (score -1):

Instead of manually editing `google-services.json`:

1. Generate a new `Client ID for Web application` from **Google cloud console > API and Services > Credentials > OAuth 2.0 client IDs**. Important that you select Web application not Android.
2. Update (or add) your debug, app signing and upload `SHA-1` certificate fingerprints to your firebase settings.
3. Now download the latest `google-services.json` from your firebase settings.
4. Replace the old `google-services.json` in your **Project > app** with the new one.
5. Now build your app.
   These steps will make Firebase auto-generate a new `Android client` in `OAuth 2.0` that will include the `Client ID for Web application` you have manually created.